# Jquery mobile framework in android OS

Tags: jquery, android, mobile

Why jquery mobile framework is slow performance in android2.2 OS

Comment: Can you elaborate on what's slow?  Is it the script loading?  Is it the rendering?  Is it the interaction?  Remember that jQuery Mobile is still in alpha, so performance is probably not optimized yet.

Comment: Thanks Johnny...It is working fine on another machine (am using emulators); makes me think it is a hardware problem. Sorry for any inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

Jose - you can't get any sense of the speed on an emulator - there is absolutely no comparison. jQuery mobile is one framework I've been evaluating also - on an iPhone 4 it is 'not bad' but still sluggish overall and on Android 2.1 it is so slow as to be nearly unusable. I'm concerned that the reuse of jQuery as a whole in the mobile side is just too big and too slow.
On a side note - Sencha Touch doesn't perform much better on Android. On iOS it is better than jQueryMobile's alpha release - that may change.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same issue: jquery mobile is not very responsive even on my Samsung Captivate (a fast, new model from mid-2010). My best guess is that it is only an alpha release, and that it will get faster once the architecture and feature set decisions are complete and it moves towards a 1.0 release.

Comment: From my own experiments and watching wire traces the problem is in the parsing/tokenization of the jQuery code.  The first time it is read in a webkit instance takes many seconds (even if the contents came from cache).  Going to another page then becomes a lot quicker presumably due to a parsed context being cached and reused.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery Mobile is currently in Beta 3 and will soon release version 1.0.  With that have come significant improvements in speed and reduced user perceived latency (UPL).  My latest mobile app runs on Android 2.2.1 and I'm using JQuery Mobile Beta 3.  It runs great!  I'm running my app on the actual device and not in a simulator.  Also, during your development, when it comes to application optimization, you might want to check out [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) and [Page Speed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/using_firefox.html) as plugin tools for Firefox/Firebug to determine the root cause of any latency issues.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is, 99,9% of available mobile frameworks are slow. This is due to:

1. Smartphones are still to slow, if you take a look at any desktop/mobile JavaScript benchmark you will see that desktop browsers always overpower mobile browsers bye far.
2. Mobile frameworks are usually slow.
3. If you want to learn latest tutorials on mobile development tutorials by building 25 projects you can follow this kickstarter link

https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1311831077/learn-5-best-mobile-development-frameworks/